# Mysql: Possible to force updating of a second column after updating the first?

Tags: mysql, security

I have a Mysql database that stores login data. The passwords and salts are saved as sha512 hashes. Now, should the value in the password column be changed, I would like to implement a condition that the salt MUST be changed, or the mysql command is invalid.

```
CREATE TABLE loginData(
id int UNSIGNED SERIAL DEFAULT VALUE,
email varchar(64) NOT NULL,
password binary(64) NOT NULL,
salt binary(64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id))
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now, I was thinking of something like the integrity constraints of foreign keys, but obviously I should not connect the password and salt column as foreign keys. Is there any way to prevent updating *only* the password column - so a new salt HAS to be given - on the *Mysql* side? Preventing it only on the side of the accessing code feels incomplete.

Comment: SQL has CHECK constraints for this sort of thing. But MySQL doesn't support them. (It parses, but does not enforce) Consider a different RDBMS instead; or forcing all calls through stored procedures that can enforce this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can possibly do it is to not actually update your login records for password changes, but to insert new records.  You would need a schema change to add a tinyint fieldname named `active` or similar to store a flag indicating which is active login.

You could then add unique indexes on email/salt and email/password in order to force uniqueness on those combinations, meaning you could never have the same email with the same salt entered and also you could never enter the same email/password combination.  Any inserts with same email/salt or email/password would fail. If you don;t need password uniqueness (you can obviously just not add the email/password unique index).

When you lookup the login to actually perform the credential check you would just have to add `WHERE active = 1` to your query filter.

You would probably also want to wrap the operation of inserting the new salt & password record and updating the old row to `active = 0` within a transaction so that either the entire transaction succeeds or fails, thus preventing cases where users get stuck without a login.

Comment: Interesting, but I think the "evil" admin (or script at that) could still just go ahead and update the password (without updating the salt), if he decided to ignore the "agreed upon" procedure of inserting new variants. Also, I think you would introduce yourself to a whole world of possible problems with double entries?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have multiple systems accessing the database, I wouldn't say preventing it only on the accessing code is incomplete. You can prevent admins from manually updating the data by not giving them the appropriate write rights on the table.

But if you must enforce this in MySQL, you could consider adding a trigger (code which is run when after updating a record), but in case the salt comes from your application, this is probably not feasible. Then the best option is to only provide access to the table through a stored procedure (code residing in the database), which enforces the integrity of the table.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-views.html

Comment: The situation is I am going to be setting the system up but probably not administrating it, so I am trying to make it as fool-proof as possible. I will try to put a trigger on the update column, but you are right, the salt does come from the application, so the case of somebody manually changing the password column might be too improbable to actually bother.